# Pimpl idiom in C++ and private constructor

Tags: c++, pimpl-idiom, private-constructor

In pimpl idiom, all private members and functions are moved to a (private) implementation class. What should be done if a class has a private constructor? Should it be moved to the implementation? If yes, how?

```
class X {
private:
    X();  // moving it to XImpl???
public:
    void DoSomething();
private:
    class XImpl;
    std::unique_ptr<XImpl> pimpl;
};
```

Comment: A private constructor is done to deny construction of the class other than through some kind of factory method. If you move that to the implementation, your interface class will get a default construcor instead -- is that what you want?

Comment: @DevSolar: Thanks for your comment/question. Another class which is a friend of `class X` is supposed to create an object of type `X`. I guess I have to have this private ctor, but I wonder what its drawbacks can be!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PIMPL is all about removing an undesired public header dependency, for various reasons. For example, C headers using the word `class` (correctness), large headers adding to the build time (work efficiency), headers with ungood macros (code brittleness). C++ accessibility, `private` versus `public` or `protected`, has nothing to do with it, although it's not at all unnatural if the accessibility correlates strongly with whether the features belong in the PIMPL class or not: usually those features will be implementation details.

Use a technique like PIMPL when you understand it and the technique is a good solution to the problem at hand.

Do not blindly apply various techniques based on cookbook-like mechanical rules. And when you clearly see that such a rule set that you're presented with, is incomplete, as here, then the proper reaction is to dismiss the rule set, not to ask for its completion. It can't be completed, the question that it leads to of what to do about a `private` constructor is meaningless.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph alone. C++ is a strange beast, and if you approach it with something like "Design Patterns" in your left and "OOP for beginners" in your right, you'll never properly harness it.